# The name "locBox does not exist"

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox

I'm using code to create a dynamic text box, including assigning it a name, and then attempting to append new text to the textbox, however I'm receiving an error that the name doesn't exist in the current context.

Am I missing something simple, or have a done something wrong? I apologize if this is a basic thing I'm doing wrong; I'm still learning.

Here's the code in question:

```
            TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
            dynamicTextBox.Name = "locBox";
            dynamicTextBox.Multiline = true;
            dynamicTextBox.Width = 300;
            dynamicTextBox.Height = 40;
            dynamicTextBox.Text = "Text ");
            dynamicTextBox.ControlAdded += locBox;

            locBox.AppendText = var1.ToString();
            locBox.AppendText = var2.ToString();
```

Comment: Your TextBox instance (the object you just created) is `dynamicTextBox`. So  `dynamicTextBox.AppendText(var1.ToString());`. `ControlAdded` is an event you really don't need to subscribe to. You then have to add `dynamicTextBox` to a Parent container to make it visible. If the Parent is the current Form, then `this.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox);`. -- I'm assuming, given the properties names, that this is a WinForms Project. You need to tag your question specifying the UI Platform.

Answer (score 0):

The locBox is not defined. you have to remove the last two statement. and change the last statement after removal too.
replace "dynamicTextBox" to the form control instance .

```
        {form instance name}.ControlAdded += locBox;
```

"{}" is a place holder.
I don't know how helpful this is.

Comment: {form instance name}.ControlAdded += dynamicTextBox;

Comment: Do you mean adding the textbox to the design form first? I've tried it that way as well; adding it to the design screen and then appending the text, but even if the textbox is already existing with the assigned name, I still get the same error. Either that one or "an obejct reference is required for the non-static field method".

Comment: Ok. can you paste the full code. so I can see the form and the text box